# Parse multiple html tags with no class names into different variables

Tags: python, html, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

So in this HTML, I want to create python variables with their respective values, I have already scraped 20K+ results and can parse the majority of the data, except I don't know how I would go about breaking this up since there are no class names and they are all under the same div.

```
<div class="callout callout-details">
  <h4>Details</h4>

  <dl class="dl-horizontal">
    <dt>Deadline:</dt>

    <dd>None</dd>

    <dt>Award type:</dt>

    <dd>Scholarship</dd>

    <dt>Award coverage:</dt>

    <dd>Other</dd>

    <dt>Renewable</dt>

    <dd>No</dd>

    <dt>Min. award:</dt>

    <dd>$2,000</dd>

    <dt>Average award:</dt>

    <dd>$2,000</dd>

    <dt>Max. award:</dt>

    <dd>$2,000</dd>

    <dt>Awarded anualy:</dt>

    <dd>No</dd>

    <dt>Unlimited awards:</dt>

    <dd>No</dd>

    <dt>Repay required:</dt>

    <dd>No</dd>
  </dl>
</div>
```

The only way I can think of is by saving all inside `<dl class="dl-horizontal">` and then split the string, but I feel like that is very time-consuming, is there any wat I can implement a for loop and saying

```
containers = page_soup.findAll("dl", {"class": "dl-horizontal"})
for container in containers:
     Deadline = container.dd
     Award = container.dd1 (and so on?)
```

I just can't seem to figure out how to properly structure the above to reach all of the `dd` fields.

Comment: Just make a dict where the keys are the dts and the values are each dt's "next" dd

Comment: I’m not sure I understand where the problem is, there are many simple ways of solving this. The first that comes to mind for me is to `.findall()` the `dt` and `dd` in two different queries, then zip the lists. The answer by Luiz Ferraz is similar, that’s a good solution too. Also, be careful of how you’re naming your variables. Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Comment: What exactly is your desired output?

Comment: @JackFleeting just the value, I am creating a giant list of scholarships with those values in a comma-separated sheet, and this will help me filter the results a lot better.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile thank you I will use that style, the problem is that I am new at web scraping so I had hit a wall during this part, thank you so much, I did not know about zip

Comment: @ArielBarboza No worries. You’re welcome, it’s a great function, so versatile. Good luck with the rest of the program :)

Answer (score 0):

Since they come in pairs, you can zip them together using slices:

```
containers = page_soup.findAll("dl", {"class": "dl-horizontal"})
names = containers.children[::2]   # Every even elements (0, 2, 4, ...)
values = containers.children[1::2] # Every off  elements (1, 3, 5, ...)
for name, value in zip(names, values):
    print(name)  # ("Deadline:", "Award type:", ...) 
    print(value) # ("None",      "Scholarship", ...)
```

Slicing works like this, consider the list `a`, you can do `a[start:end:step]`. It will return a new list starting from the `start` value up to the one before `end` (it doesn't include it). And will include only every `step`nd values.

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

# Leaving start blank is same as 0.
# And leaving end blank is same as the length of a, so include all elements
a[:]     => ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
a[::2]   => ['a', 'c']
a[1::2]  => ['b', 'd']

# Zip groups elements of multiple lists aligned
zip(a[::2], a[1::2]) => [('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd')]
```

Comment: I haven't noticed what @pguardiario mentioned that the values are already in different tags... You could just get them using `find`, but I'll leave my answer because slices are fun.

Comment: Thank you! I was not aware of that, researched a bit and was not advancing, this helped a lot!

Comment: Will this work, despite the fact that `containers` is a list? Don’t you need to iterate and call `children` on each element of the list?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile it did not work but learned about zip and was able to iterate through list thanks all